# Breaking boxplot xlim interval

Tags: r

My boxplot has a range 1 to 121 on the x axis, with breaks of 1.

My boxplot code:

```
boxplot(data, xlab="No f bags", xlim=(1,121))
```

How can I plot the boxplot by applying breaks to axis follows:

1, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the example below:

`data<-data.frame(a=runif(200,min=1,max=121))`

`boxplot(data$a,xlab='No f bags',ylim=c(1,121),yaxt='n')`

[image]

The `yaxt` argument in `boxplot` removes the default y-axis labeling R provides.

`axis(side=2,at=c(1,20,40,60,80,100,120))`

[image]

The final line of code with the `axis` function now tells R to establish a new y-axis at the following breaks.