# How to change y-axis scale in a R boxplot function?

Tags: r, scale, boxplot

When I do a boxplot diagram with the R `boxplot`function, this function prints the y-axis automatically.

```
library(datasets)

boxplot(cars[c('speed', 'dist')],
        col = "lightgray")
```

In the `?boxplot` I found the `ylim` parameter that change the y-axis limits, but not change the scale. So I tried to use the `axis` function to divide the scale from 0 to 120 every 10:
`axis(4, at = seq(0, 120, 10))`.  But I'm not getting a satisfactory result.

I can't see where I'm making mistakes. Could someone help with this question?
Thanks in advance.

[image: boxplot]

Comment: Maybe `boxplot(..., yaxt = "n")` followed by `axis(2, at = seq(0, 120, 10), las = 2)`.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32256208/breaking-boxplot-xlim-interval) is a similar question which is supporting the  @RuiBarradas 's comment.

Comment: Hi @RuiBarradas it's worked fine! Thank you for your support. Could you make an answer, please?  I didn't understand why `las = 2` and not `las = 1`.

Comment: Hi @maydin. I think this question is a little bit different. Because I could only make a segmented y-axis  using the `las` argument in the `axis` function.

Comment: Done, see the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(datasets)
boxplot(cars[c('speed', 'dist')], col = "lightgray", ylim = range(0:120), yaxs = "i")
axis(4, at=seq(0, 120, 10))
```

[image]

The y-axis is on the right-hand side as you wanted I believe.

Comment: What does this do?

Comment: correct implementation to put every 10 increments on vertical axes.

Comment: Hi @Vitali Avagyan, your answer didn't work for me. How can you see plotting the diagram, its did not return the boxplot with the y-axis segmented every 10. Thank you for your support.

Comment: That's strange, I was able to get it. I will try to add the result.

Comment: @cladius, I have edited the post and put the result which was produced by a run of the same exact code that is written in my answer. Can you confirm at least that it is what you are after? Thanks.

Comment: Now it worked fine. =)  Thank you again for the support.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ggpubr` instead. It let's you treat it as a `gg` object.

```
librabry(ggpubr)
library(reshape2)
df <- melt(cars)
p <- ggpubr::ggboxplot(data = df, x = "variable", y = "value", width = 0.8) +
  ggtitle("Plot of car") +
  xlab("my-xalabel") + ylab("my-ylabel")
>p
```

[image]

If you want in log scale:

```
p + ggpubr::yscale("log2", .format = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @MAPK, your answer didn't work for me.  It's not about boxplot function.  And did not return the boxplot diagram with the y-axis segmented every 10. Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering because the OP said in a comment that my comment did the job. I will also explain the code here.

There are two tricks to consider:

1. First plot without the `y`axis by setting argument `yaxt = "n"`.
2. Then plot the axis number 2, with the labels always  perpendicular to the axis. This is done with `las = 2`.

So the final code is the following.

```
library(datasets)

boxplot(cars[c('speed', 'dist')],
        col = "lightgray", yaxt = "n")
axis(2, at = seq(0, 120, 10), las = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried `las = 1`and it worked too. But `las = 3` not work. I'm trying to understand how the `las` parameter as connected with the segmentation of y-axis. Looks like informagic.

Comment: @claudius The reference is the [official documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/par.html): `las = 1` means *"always horizontal"*; `las = 2` means *"always perpendicular to the axis* and `las = 3` is *"always vertical"*. And it's working with me.